# No output from command executed over ssh on SUSE with openBSD sshd

Tags: ssh, remote

Trying to execute command via ssh, but I'm not receiving anything back. The server A is Solaris machine and Server B is SUSE linux with OpenBSD sshd. Checked

> 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569588/ssh-remote-command-does-not-return
> 2. https://www.openbsd.org/papers/auug2002-ssh.pdf
> 3. https://superuser.com/questions/792070/commands-over-ssh-not-producing-output

and other sources, but can't resolve it.

The command I'm trying is (in bash):

```
    ssh -v -i .ssh/id_rsa -p1234 user2@abcdefg 'ls -al'
```

(tried without quotes and with double quotes as well )

EDIT: 
I enabled Loglevl on sshd side and got following from auth file

```
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[2162]: debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[2162]: debug1: Forked child 10616.
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[2162]: debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 270
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[2162]: debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[2162]: debug3: send_rexec_state: done
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: oom_adjust_restore
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: Connection from 10.0.0.1 port 29325
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version Sun_SSH_1.1.6
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: no match: Sun_SSH_1.1.6
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: Network child is on pid 10617
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: preauth child monitor started
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: privsep user:group 71:65 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 71/65 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,arcfour,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,arcfour,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: i-default [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: i-default [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 118 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 119 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 118
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 119
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 118 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 119 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 118
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 119
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 0 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_choose_dh: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_MODULI [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 1 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_moduli: got parameters: 1536 2048 8192
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 1
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: monitor_read: 0 used once, disabling now
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_choose_dh: remaining 0 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 135/256 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: bits set: 1024/2048 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: bits set: 1061/2048 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_sign
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_sign: signature 0x7fb4778c19a0(271)
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: kex_derive_keys [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: userauth-request for user some_user service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.0.0.1.
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 270
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: checking match for 'Group com-ldap' user some_user host 10.0.0.1 addr 10.0.0.1 subsystem (null) laddr 172.16.16.196 lport 4422
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: user some_user does not match group list com-ldap at line 22
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: match not found
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for some_user [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_start_pam entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 100 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 100
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "some_user"
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.0.0.1"
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: monitor_read: 100 used once, disabling now
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: userauth-request for user some_user service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x7fb4778c1ce0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 501/108 (e=0/0)
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: trying public key file /home/some_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: matching key found: file /home/some_user/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: Found matching RSA key: d9:1a:b3:fe:c7:fc:41:5c:ac:dc:6c:09:84:c7:ed:54 [MD5]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7fb4778c1ce0 is allowed
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: Postponed publickey for some_user from 10.0.0.1 port 29325 ssh2 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: userauth-request for user some_user service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 0 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x7fb4778c1de0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 501/108 (e=0/0)
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: trying public key file /home/some_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: matching key found: file /home/some_user/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: Found matching RSA key: d9:1a:b3:fe:c7:fc:41:5c:ac:dc:6c:09:84:c7:ed:54 [MD5]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7fb4778c1de0 is allowed
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_key_verify entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 24 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_key_verify: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYVERIFY [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 25 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 24
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_keyverify: key 0x7fb4778c1dc0 signature verified
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 25
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 102
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: do_pam_account: called
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: PAM: do_pam_account pam_acct_mgmt = 0 (Success)
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 103
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: Accepted publickey for some_user from 10.0.0.1 port 29325 ssh2
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: monitor_child_preauth: some_user has been authenticated by privileged process
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for new keys
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 26
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_newkeys_from_blob: 0x7fb4778d30d0(122)
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for second key
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_newkeys_from_blob: 0x7fb4778d30d0(122)
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Getting compression state
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Getting Network I/O buffers
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 120
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 121
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 1 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_do_pam_account entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 102 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 103 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_do_pam_account returning 1 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: Sending new keys: 0x7fb4778c2a80 0x7fb4778b95b0 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_newkeys_to_blob: converting 0x7fb4778c2a80 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_newkeys_to_blob: converting 0x7fb4778b95b0 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: New keys have been sent [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: Sending compression state [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 26 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: Finished sending state [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 120 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 121 [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync end
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: PAM: opening session
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: User child is on pid 10618
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 501/108
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 198720 max 32768
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: input_session_request
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_new: session 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_open: channel 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request exec reply 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req exec
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: mm_audit_run_command entering command ls -al
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 113
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 114
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 113
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_audit_command entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug1: session_new: session 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 114
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: fd 11 setting O_NONBLOCK
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_by_pid: pid 10619
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 10619
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: request exit-status confirm 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: write failed
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: close_write
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: send eow
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: output open -> closed
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 9 len 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: read failed
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: close_read
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: read 0 from efd 11
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: closing read-efd 11
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: send eof
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: send close
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: notify_done: reading
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: is dead
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0 child 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: session_close: session 0 pid 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: mm_audit_end_command entering command ls -al
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 115
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: is dead
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: channel 0: free: server-session, nchannels 1
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:\r\n  #0 server-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)\r\n
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: Connection closed by 10.0.0.1
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug1: do_cleanup
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 120
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 121
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 115
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_answer_audit_end_command entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_session_close: session 0 pid 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_session_close: command 0
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 120
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10616]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 121
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: Transferred: sent 2800, received 1584 bytes
Oct 20 15:24:22 SC-2-2 sshd[10618]: Closing connection to 10.0.0.1 port 29325
```

EDIT:
    `.bashrc file
    test -s ~/.alias && . ~/.alias || true
    # apos_skelconf.sh: adding custom PATH settings to new-created users
    DIR_LIST='/sbin /usr/sbin /bin'
    for DIR in $DIR_LIST; do
        if [[ ! "$PATH" =~ ^${DIR}/*:|:${DIR}/*:|:${DIR}/*$ ]]; then
                export PATH=${PATH}:${DIR}
        fi
    done
    export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
    export EDITOR=vi
    shopt -s checkwinsize
    umask 022`

Comment: SUSE linux with OpenBSD sshd or OpenBSD? What's the OS on the 2 machine?

Comment: will ssh with out commands connect you ? your debug line suggest an eof after ls is send.

Comment: How does your `authorized_keys` file on the server look like?

Comment: indeed its SUSE linux with OpenBSD sshd on server side and Solaris on client side

Comment: authorized_keys on server side looks like 'code' ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEAw+MR6e7Urn...........=

Comment: The log is not complete. The important part is earlier.

Comment: How does your `~/.bashrc` or other startup files on the server look like? Does the login work for other users?

Comment: hmm struggeling with pasting whole log as I reached the limit of characters in the body

Comment: @Jakuje login does work, only I'm not receiving anything back from command. If I login with ssh and then eecute the command its all OK and I get the output

Comment: deleted other logs and now I'm able to past whole log from /var/logs/auth o server side

Comment: What about the bash/shell startup scripts? `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: i added the .bashrc file

Comment: I'm having this same issue on an Ubuntu 16.10 x86_64 doing `ssh localhost ls`. There is no output and my log is pretty much similar to @taiko

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is relevant for your case but I was able to solve a similar problem on an Ubuntu 16.10 by editing `.bashrc`:

From:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) exit;;
esac
```

To:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

So if you can find an `exit` anywhere on your config files, maybe that's what's doing the *nasties*.

Just replace it with a `return`.

Cheers,
Gus

Comment: will definitelt ty it